# the function is not linked to a photo

Tags: javascript, html

In theory, when the cursor approaches the photo, the picture should run away from the mouse to a random place, but I've been sitting for an hour and I can't understand why it doesn't work. Help plz((

```js
let Left, Top, MaxLeft, MaxTop;
let image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLT0j7uXO5xZs2Ovqr97bnSTb8leTEZqu9zlPyLFGg=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj";
image.width = "300";
image.height = "300";

let div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.id = 'im'
div1.append(image);
document.body.append(div1);
elem = document.getElementById('im');

MaxLeft = document.documentElement.clientWidth - elem.offsetWidth;
MaxTop = document.documentElement.clientHeight - elem.offsetHeight;
elem.onmousemove = handler;

function handler() {
  Left = Math.random() * MaxLeft;
  elem.style.left = Left + 'px';
  Top = Math.random() * MaxTop;
  elem.style.top = Top + 'px';
  console.log(Left + ' - ' + Top);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Кошки-мышки, наверное</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default CSS `position` property of the `div` is `static` and when the `position` is set to that, changing the `top` and `left` properties has no effect ([more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values)).

To fix that, you can change the `div`'s position to `relative`, something like this:

```
div1.style.position = 'relative';
```

Here is a working example, I've made the image smaller so it will fit.

```js
let Left, Top, MaxLeft, MaxTop;
let image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLT0j7uXO5xZs2Ovqr97bnSTb8leTEZqu9zlPyLFGg=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj";
image.width = "50";
image.height = "50";

let div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.id = 'im'
div1.style.position = 'relative';
div1.append(image);
document.body.append(div1);
elem = document.getElementById('im');

MaxLeft = document.documentElement.clientWidth - elem.offsetWidth;
MaxTop = document.documentElement.clientHeight - elem.offsetHeight;
elem.onmousemove = handler;

function handler() {
  Left = Math.random() * MaxLeft;
  elem.style.left = Left + 'px';
  Top = Math.random() * MaxTop;
  elem.style.top = Top + 'px';
  console.log(Left + ' - ' + Top);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Кошки-мышки, наверное</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```